# why is readdir not multi thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

Thanks for reading this question, I only have basic C knowledge and I am not familiar with linux system.
Here is what i know about readdir：

1. someone said that readdir() is not multi thread safe beacuse it uses **static varible**,so that readdir can be described as this

```
    struct dirent* readdir() {
     static struct dirent; //read action 
     return &dirent;
    }
```

2. However, the actual glibc implementation is multi thread safe when you use readdir() to different dirstream (which is DIR struct), but not safe when you read the same dirstream (https://lwn.net/Articles/696474/)
3. readdir_r has been deprecated since glibc 2.24. Here is the reason
   https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir_r.3.html

My question:

1. i did not see any static varible in glibc source code, where is the static varible?
   Here is the source code I read. I can only see that it uses lock to ensure multi thread safe
   https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/readdir.c
2. I try to use multi thread to read same dirstream such as:
   DIR* des_dir=opendir(xxx);
   pthread_create(pid,0,custom_readdir,des_dir);
   Each thread shares the same dirstream, and the result is OK. Each thread outputs part of the directory correctly, so how do I understand "In cases where multiple threads read from the same directory stream unsafe?"
3. If readdir() is indeed unsafe, how can I read a directory in a safe way? I did not find a function which can replace readdir().

Comment: It is unsafe because it is documented as unsafe. Rationales such as the static variable may help to understand why it is unsafe and remember it, but may blind you to other reasons so should not be taken too much as the final truth. Races may give some bad behaviour only rarely or in special circumstances (on other arch that x86, only when the directory is above a given size...). If you want a safe readdir, just use a mutex to sequentialize the calls.

Comment: *readdir_r has been deprecated since glibc 2.24.*  "On systems where `NAME_MAX` is undefined, calling `readdir_r()` may be unsafe because the interface does not allow the caller to specify the length of the buffer used for the returned directory entry."  [**OH FFS that's pathetic**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/readdir_r.html): "Either the `{NAME_MAX}` compile-time constant **or the corresponding `pathconf()` option can be used to determine the maximum sizes of returned pathnames**."  GLIBC: "Our `readdir_r` sucks, plz deprecate cuz we can't fix it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i did not see any static varible in glibc source code, where is the static varible?

There is no static variable. The code you pointed to uses a buffer in the directory stream to hold and return `struct dirent` objects. So it is unsafe to use multiple threads with the same directory stream because they could conflict over use of the single buffer.

> I try to use multi thread to read same dirstream such as:
> DIR* des_dir=opendir(xxx);
> pthread_create(pid,0,custom_readdir,des_dir);
> Each thread shares the same dirstream, and the result is OK. Each thread outputs part of the directory correctly,…

You got unlucky in your experiment; the execution of the threads happened to fail to conflict. The buffer used does have room for multiple `struct dirent`, allowing some opportunity for multiple threads to use different parts, making observation of a failure less likely, especially when testing with only a few directories.

> If readdir() is indeed unsafe, how can I read a directory in a safe way?

Open a separate directory stream for each thread. Or use one thread to read the directory stream and have it copy the desired directory information and pass it to other threads to do the work for the directories.

Answer (score 1):

> If readdir() is indeed unsafe, how can I read a directory in a safe way?

In all POSIXy systems, you can use [`scandir()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html), [`scandirat()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandirat.3.html), [`glob()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), and [`nftw()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html).  `nftw()` is the best option for traversing entire directory trees (looking for specific files), `scandir()`/`scandirat()` for scanning individual directories.

Of these, `scandir()` and `scandirat()` are thread-safe; and `nftw()` is thread-safe except wrt. current working directory during traversal.

In Linux and BSDs, you can also use the [`<fts.h>`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) functions.